# How to tell which children is last in Angular ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have two components list (parent) and item (child)
I would like to set different style to last child component.
How can we achieve that ? In parent component I am iterating over child component. I was trying to get *ngFor index (according to angular documentation) and set class like this:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <app-item *ngFor="let traceGroup of tracesGroup; index as i"
            [traceGroup]="traceGroup";
            [class.isLast]="i + 1 === tracesGroup.length"></app-item>
</ul>
```

But i get an error

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ';' is not a valid attribute name.

I also tried to get index this way `; let i = index`
however there's still error even if I delete semicolon.
What's wrong with the code and what's the best practice to 'mark' somehow from parent to child component so you know which child component is last ?
Thanks

Comment: you can use *ngFor="...;let last=last", see https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
[traceGroup]="traceGroup";
                        ^^^
                      remove this
```

Comment: och sorry. I Didn't notice that. Thanks for help